# mySQL - Selecting a column from another table that is not in the current table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to learn SQL and am having trouble joining two tables in order to select the column I want. There are two tables, A4DEL and A4SPL, that have the information I need. This information is the delivery number (DELNO), supplier (SPLNAME), and department (DEPTNAME) that have ordered the item 'Sextant'. From A4DEL I can get DELNO and DEPTNAME but I still need SPLNAME from the A4SPL table. A4DEL and A4SPL only share SPLNO as an attribute and I'm not sure how to join them properly in order to pull SPLNAME from A4SPL.

```
SELECT DELNO, A4SPL.SPLNAME, DEPTNAME
FROM A4DEL
WHERE
A4DEL.SPLNO = A4SPL.SPLNAME
AND
ITEMNAME = 'Sextant'
```

Comment: You might want to look into table joins

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.DELNO, b.SPLNAME, a.DEPTNAME
FROM A4DEL a
LEFT JOIN A4SPL b
ON a.SPLNO = a.SPLNO
WHERE DEPTNAME = 'Sextant';
```